# Responsive Background?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background, responsive

How can I integrate the attached background into a respnosive website? There is also a mobile view attached and the Backgrtound only.

I have tried it as an SVG graphic, but it doesn't work well because it always scales strangely and is not responsive. Also with "clip-path" in CSS it didn't work for me.

Also a PNG/JPG image is not good, because the quality is bad or the file is too big.

How can I display this background that is **absolutely responsive**? It should be displayable for mobile phones if possible but also 4k (8k).

I am looking forward to any answer!

Images: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1olJcDIMsbi2mAEbbr9vyf9n74ENaMeWB

Comment: Could you share me the code you already have? thank you

Comment: Read More!
https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/

Answer (score 0):

Check this out this might help

```css
img {
width: 30%;
display: inline-block
}
body {
background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/SPBfZxS/bg1-1.png);
background-size: cover;
color: white;
}
button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #2BBBAD; 
    color: white;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    user-select: none;
    transition: all .2s;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
img {
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.hero-image {
  background-image: url("/w3images/photographer.jpg");
  background-color: #cccccc;
  height: 400px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1 style="font-size:50px">I am [YOUR_NAME_HERE]</h1>
    <h3>[INSERT_TAGLINE_HERE]</h3>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="padding:20px">
<p>Page content..</p>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, you need to use the @media selector

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
img {
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But here is the problem with the SVG... graphics. If I make the website narrow like on a mobile phone, you can see the footer without scrolling down. Because the graphic is always displayed in the full size. That means it must always be 100% in length, but cut off from left + right.

Or do I have to create a new image for each size that is a little narrower. With the media queries?

Comment: Code: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1aFRXsTZQrOFFvk5Ep2jT37QrDUntlK8s

Comment: Ok, just wrap a parent div around the SVG. then it will work

Comment: Like this: `<div class="image"><svg></svg> </div>`

Comment: and an @media rule: `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.image {
width: 100%;
}`

Comment: I did it the way you told me, but the background is too small. Is there something wrong in my code? This is my Code: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1aFRXsTZQrOFFvk5Ep2jT37QrDUntlK8s